# How to make a simple paging on Kotlin with Gridview?

Tags: json, gridview, kotlin, android-volley, paging

I have a json request witch brings me 20 objects with offset and limit http://website.com/myRestApi/getObjects.php?offset=20. I want to call it every time user scrolling on Gridview and loads the 20, so to create an infinite simple paging style within my Android App until objects finish!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html

Comment: Something more easy? I want to do it without additional library. Just Kotlin and Gridview

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way actually, you just call `gridView.setOnScrollListener(listener)` and in listener's method `onScroll` you're loading more items if current visible position if last visible position is equal to totalItems, in summary you do this:

```
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(object: AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
        override fun onScroll(view: AbsListView?, firstVisibleItem: Int, visibleItemCount: Int, totalItemCount: Int) {
            if (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount <= firstVisibleItem && adapter.count + ITEM_COUNT <= MAX_ITEM_COUNT) {
                //TODO: Add footer or some progress view to show that items are loading
                loadMore()
            }
        }
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(view: AbsListView?, state: Int) {
            //TODO: add some logic if needed, but no logic needed for this task
        }
    })
```

Where `totalItemCount - visibleItemCount <= firstVisibleItem` is equal to `totalItemCount - lastVisibleItemPosition == 0`, `ITEM_COUNT` is 20 for you, and last condition `adapter.count + ITEM_COUNT <= MAX_ITEM_COUNT` should be made only if you have maximum count of items on server. **You should execute your request in `loadMore()`**

Answer (score 0):

here is the listener of pagination. Please add your logic accordingly

```
  gridview.setOnScrollChangeListener(object : AbsListView.OnScrollListener, View.OnScrollChangeListener {
            override fun onScrollChange(v: View?, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int) {
                print("ff")
            }

            override fun onScroll(
                view: AbsListView?,
                firstVisibleItem: Int,
                visibleItemCount: Int,
                totalItemCount: Int
            ) {

            }

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(view: AbsListView?, scrollState: Int) {

            }

        })
    }
```

comment if you need further help.